# How can I prove to the IRS that I didn't receive income that an employer incorrectly reported?

Tags: united-states, irs, contractor

I received a notice from the IRS a few days ago regarding my 2012 filing. One of the companies I contracted for filed paperwork stating they paid me about twice what I actually received. It seems like it may just be an honest mistake, but I can't be certain. That company no longer exists, as far as I know. The letter I received has a form were I can reject their changes, but I also have to include supporting documentation for my case. What proof can I provide to the IRS that will satisfy them? I don't know how I can show them a lack of paychecks from my client.

---

I ended up sending in another copy of the 1099 I received from the company. This seemed to satiate the IRS and now they say I don't owe them any money at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should include the checks you received from the company, invoices you sent, bank statements showing the deposits, and your receipts, if any, you issued to the company.

You'd be surprised to know that this is a fairly common tax fraud. You can also try and sue the company or its successor for the missing amounts, but if it has been dissolved it may be difficult.

As with any non-trivial tax issue - I suggest you get a professional advice from a EA/CPA licensed in your State. You may need representation before the IRS - only EA, CPA or an Attorney may represent you in IRS proceedings (including audit and correspondence).

Comment: Do you mean "fraud" because the company he contracted with could have claimed twice the cost, reduced their profit and their tax payments?

Comment: @gnasher729 exactly